# How to get this Twitter javascript to only show 3 updates

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I found this easy to use JavaScript for www.twitter.com updates to place on my website. When I edited the code to what my username and then placed it in my index.html the code was showing all of my status updates. I would like to only have this script show 2 or 3 of my newest updates. How can I make this work? What needs to get added into the script?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.gtaero.net/twitter/twitter.php?user=USERNAME"></script>
<div id="twitFeed">Optional Placeholder Text</div>
<script type="text/javascript">twitter2id("twitFeed");</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this URL into your browser:

http://www.gtaero.net/twitter/twitter.php?user=USERNAME

See that the script is full of documentation

The answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.gtaero.net/twitter/twitter.php?user=USERNAME&count=3"></script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.gtaero.net/twitter/twitter.php?user=wlshafor&count=2"></script>
<div id="twitFeed"></div>
<script #twitFeed a { color: yellow;};</script>
<script type="text/javascript">twitter2id("twitFeed");</script>    
     <div class="twitter_div"></div>
    
     <a href="http://www.twitter.com/wlshafor" title="Follow Me!" class="twitter-follow">Follow Me!</a>

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.gtaero.net/twitter/

> How to use.
>   (Look below for an example)
>   http://www.gtaero.net/twitter/
>
> ```
> [optional]  [DEFAULT]  navarr  ?user   =USERNAME          STR  
> [optional]  [DEFAULT]  10      &count  =NUMBER_TO_SHOW    INT 0-20  
> [optional]  [DEFAULT]  true    &time   =DISPLAY_TIME      BOOL[true,false]  Display the Time of the Tweet  
> [optional]  [DEFAULT]  true    &client =DISPLAY_CLIENT    BOOL[true,false]  Display the Client the tweet was posted from  
> [optional]  [DEFAULT]  true    &br     =BREAK_TWEET_TIME  BOOL[true,false]  Break the Tweet and the Time in HTML (<br />)
> [optional]  [DEFAULT]  false   &turl   =USE_TURLED        BOOL[true,false]  Use Turled profile links instead of twitter
> [optional]  [DEFAULT]  5       &cache  =MINUTES_TO_CACHE  INT >= 5          The number of minutes (greater than or equal to five) to cache tweets.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Example of URL with variables: `http://gtaero.net/twitter/?user=navarr&count=5`

These are variables for the URL. You already have `user`. So you need:

```
http://www.gtaero.net/twitter/?user=USERNAME&count=3
```

Comment: I did but I do not understand where to place the count at

Comment: Same place you put the username, the URL To the script.

Comment: I can I change the default color of what the url link is & also who I re tweeted from? say like [HELP] How to get this Twitter javascript to only show 3 updates. http://t.co/seibIJr
about 33 minutes ago... The link & time is in Blue I would like to make the url link white & the time yellow.

Comment: @Warren: Have a look at the generated HTML and create corresponding CSS rules.

Comment: This is what I am using the script for http://colorblinddesigns.com/ I it is just something extra to add to my site.

Comment: @Warren: So you can just create a rule `#twitFeed a { color: yellow;}`. This will turn all links in feeds yellow.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> #twitFeed a { color: yellow;};</script>

Comment: @Warren: No, it is a CSS rule. You have to add it to your stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you for the help I am super tired & its 12:30am & I have class at 8:30am lol time for bed thanks a lot for the help.